# Importing from lxml.etree fails on Python 3.4 running RHEL 2.6.18-371.11.1.el5

Tags: python, lxml

I installed the latest version of lxml.etree compatible with Python 3.4. However when I try importing the package, I hit the following error:

```
 > python
Python 3.4.1 (default, Nov 12 2014, 13:34:29)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from lxml import etree
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /users/vinapai/nxapi/pyats/lib/python3.4/site-packages/lxml/etree.cpython-34m.so: undefined symbol: xmlMemDisplayLast
>>>
```

I tried using both pip install and easy_install and tried different packages of lxml but consistently hit this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: from /users/vinapai/nxapi/pyats/lib/python3.4/site-packages/, what does `ll -d *lxml*` show you? More than one egg file?

Comment: @HappyLeapSecond: I am using RHEL 2.6.18-371.11.1.el5

Comment: @cameron-f: The output is 
drwxr-xr-x 6 vinapai eng 4096 Jun 25 14:09 lxml
drwxr-xr-x 2 vinapai eng 4096 Jun 25 14:09 lxml-3.0.1-py3.4.egg-info

Comment: Did you install `libxslt-devel` and `cssselect`?

Comment: [From here](http://lxml.de/installation.html) it suggests you need python3-lxml.  Have you installed that?

Comment: @VinayPai There have been a few new releases since 3.0.1.  Upgrading might help.  `pip install --upgrade lxml`

Comment: upgrading does not help. Nor does installing `cssselect`. I tried installing `libxslt-devel` and `python3-lxml` and it mentions that there are no such packages available. I am trying using `pip install`.

Comment: To install python3-lxml would be `sudo apt-get install python3-lxml` or whatever red hat's equivalent is.